# Spring SAML 2.0

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I recently inherited a project that is using Spring SAML 2.0 but the code does not seem to be validating X509 certificate.  I can see that it is validating the the time stamps and the signature values but not the cert itself.  I'm having some trouble finding documentation that clearly explains the process for validating the cert, does anyone here either have a location where I can find the information I seek or a have the ability to explain it.

Comment: Do you mean that Spring SAML does not validate the certificate validity etc?

Comment: so in my testing I replaced the existing cert with an expired cert and I was still able to access the page.  if I change the time stamps or the destination URL or most any other parameter I can force it to fail. An expired cert does not cause a failure though.  I assume I am missing some detail in the code.

Comment: The certificate validities are not checked with the default metaIOP security profile, in case you would like these to be verified, use pkix security profile instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SAML 2 specification just states that the Service Provider (i.e. consuming application) should validate the signature, it does not require the SP to perform any validation on the certificate itself i.e. no check is required for the certificate expiration or the validity of the certificate chain etc. In fact the SAML spec recommends the use of long lived self-signed certificates, short lived certificates or certificates that are signed by a CA are discouraged. For more information see [this](https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/InCCollaborate/X.509+Certificates+in+Metadata) article.

This explains why Spring SAML (and most SAML2 implementations) will not perform validation on the x509 certificate